# Отключить проверку ssl сертификата в aiohttp ClientSession

Tags: python, ssl, aiohttp

Как я могу отключить проверку ssl сертификата в aiohttp ClientSession.
У меня происходит такая ошибка:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-7' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:409> exception=ClientConnectorCertificateError(ConnectionKey(host='sba.yandex.net', port=443, is_ssl=True, ssl=None, proxy=None, proxy_auth=None, proxy_headers_hash=None), SSLCertVerificationError(1, "[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid for 'sba.yandex.net'. (_ssl.c:1129)"))>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 969, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1081, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1111, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 528, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 188, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 944, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid for 'sba.yandex.net'. (_ssl.c:1129)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 417, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 238, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 286, in process_update
    return await self.callback_query_handlers.notify(update.callback_query)
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "c:\Users\Maxim\Desktop\bot\telegrambot.py", line 41, in callback_handler
    await music_parse(call)
  File "c:\Users\Maxim\Desktop\bot\telegrambot.py", line 59, in music_parse
    async with session.get(call.data) as response:
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 520, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 535, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 892, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1051, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1020, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 971, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host sba.yandex.net:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, "[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid for 'sba.yandex.net'. (_ssl.c:1129)")]
```

Comment: Я бы советовал никогда не отключать проверку сертификата сервера, иначе можно нарваться на атаку [MITM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0), в итоге кто-то лишний получит доступ к передаваемым данным.

Comment: Не думаю, что это так важно, когда просто пытаешься использовать api сокращателя ссылок

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы отключить проверку сертификата в aiohtttp Client Session, необходимо просто написать в скобки с url, `ssl=False`